# Appending a line break to an output file in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, append

I have a shell script that I am executing in Cygwin (maybe this is the problem). For this bit of code, I simply want to write the first line, and append a line break:

```
echo "`date` User `whoami` started the script." >> output.log
echo >> output.log
```

But the output.log file never seems to take the break. If I run the script multiple times, it's as if the second echo doesn't write to the file.

I've also tried:

```
echo -e "`date` User `whoami` started the script.\n" >> output.log
```

It yields the same results.

The odd thing is if I just enter the second echo statement above on the command line, without appending to the file, it gives me the expected output with the trailing line break.

Comment: Strange. How do you determine that the newlines are not added?

Comment: Actually, I just looked at it seems the program I'm opening the log in is not interpreting the LF correctly, and is expecting Windows line breaks. If I cat the output, it seems to honor the breaks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'm betting the problem is that Cygwin is writing Unix line endings (LF) to the file, and you're opening it with a program that expects Windows line-endings (CRLF). To determine if this is the case — and for a bit of a hackish workaround — try:

```
echo "`date` User `whoami` started the script."$'\r' >> output.log
```

(where the `$'\r'` at the end is an extra carriage-return; it, plus the Unix line ending, will result in a Windows line ending).

Comment: This worked perfectly. The hypothesis about Unix vs Windows line endings seemed to be the problem

Answer (score 25):

Try:

```
echo "`date` User `whoami` started the script."$'\n' >> output.log
```

or just:

```
echo $'\n' >> output.log
```

Comment: Note that command-substitution is not performed within `$'...'`, so that version will print the actual string, backticks and "date" and "whoami" and all, rather than running the `date` and `whoami` commands.

Comment: @ruakh - Good catch. I did not notice that. I updated my answer.

Comment: The "$'\n' did not work, needed to do the "$'\r' from ruakh's solution. Thanks so much though!

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
echo -en "`date` User `whoami` started the script.\n" >> output.log
```

Try issuing this multiple times. I hope you are looking for the same output.

Answer (score 5):

this also works, and prolly is more readable than the echo version:

```
printf "`date` User `whoami` started the script.\r\n" >> output.log
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that without an I/O redirection:

```
sed -i 's/$/\n/' filename
```

You can also use this command to append a newline to a list of files:

```
find dir -name filepattern | xargs sed -i 's/$/\n/' filename
```

For `echo`, some shells implement it as a shell builtin command. It might not accept the `-e` option. If you still want to use `echo`, try to find where the `echo` binary file is, using `which echo`. In most cases, it is located in `/bin/echo`, so you can use `/bin/echo -e "\n"` to echo a new line.