# How to print a newline in bash without echo -e?

Tags: bash

I wrote this function in bash that basically loops each file I have in my main directory that ends with `.m` and then in each file reads line by line and takes from this line: place, name, points and print it.

My problem is that after `echo`, the function doesn't print a newline. 
I can't use `echo -e` which I saw many solutions like this but I can't find solutions without using it .

Here is an idea of what I am working with:

```
function print {  
for file in *.m; do  
   while read f ; do             
  local name="`get_name $num`"
  local points="`get_points $num`"
  local place="`echo "$f" | get_place $2`"
  echo "$file $name $points $place"
 done < "$file"
 done 
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't print a newline? Do you want to print mulitple newlines? Why can't you use `-e`? Also printf is superior to echo in practically every situation so, so you may want to consider using that instead.

Comment: You can use `echo $'\r'` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741433/appending-a-line-break-to-an-output-file-in-a-shell-script

Comment: i want in each loop to print a new line after printing the name and pointes .. cause right now the function print everything in the same line .. i can't use -e as requisted from our prof .. also the prof saied he prefare us to use only echo ! i don't know why

Comment: i tried "echo $'\r'" and it also not working :/

Comment: There's something wrong with your TTY, or your terminal emulator, or some other external factor. `echo "$file $name $points $place"` absolutely prints a newline.

Comment: yeah it worked finally the problem was in the way i called the function

Comment: Ignore the `function` keyword; just use POSIX-style function declarations: `print () { ... }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this instead of `echo`: `printf "\n"`

Comment: Just to be sure I also tried and it works. GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)